# How to grant select on dba_users for role?

Tags: oracle, roles, sql-grant

It is possible to make grant select on dba_users to role? I trying to give access for users and all works fine, but when i try to do this for all group, this access didnt work.

Comment: Did you try to select from DBA_USERS inside a PL/SQL program?

Comment: Yes,  i want to use this select to update another table, but procedure with query is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privileges which are granted through a role do not apply inside PL/SQL blocks. You have to grant the privilege to each **USER** individually.

See [How Roles Work in PL/SQL Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#i1007304)